# How to get a local copy of the SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I'm triyng to migrate my SVN repository to a Git one. In order to do that, I have to have my svn repository locally in my machine. So far I tried `svn checkout`, `git svn clone`, `svndump`, and none worked. I found `rsync`, but that also gives an error which I can't get rid of.

I execute the following command in the directory where I want it to copy the repository:

`rsync -a . username@domain.host:http://someAddress/svn/repoName`

and get the following error.

`ssh: Could not resolve domain.host: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]`

Can anyone give an example of a simple use case of this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Tried the following:

```
svnadmin dump http://someAddress/svn/Reponame > Reponame-svn.out
```

and got the error of:

```
svnadmin: 'http://someAddress/svn/Reponame' is an URL when it should be a path
```

So, this also does not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have direct access to the Subversion server and you're using a recent client (which you should be), you can use [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump) to create a dumpfile which you can then load into a local repository, making a copy of the full repository **at that point in time** which you can then convert to git.

If you do have direct access to the server, use `svnadmin dump` on the server to create the same dumpfile, then transfer to wherever you're working, load into a new repository, and run your conversion.

Comment: I am not on the server machine, so I need something which I can execute on my own machine (granted the authorized credentials from the server) and get the copy of the repository, so that I  can migrate it to a Git repository.

Comment: Also, `svnrdump: command not found`, I am using version 1.6.17 .

Comment: @frageDE If you don't have access to the server, `svnrdump` is your solution (assuming you have read access to every path you need in the repository). You need to upgrade your client - you're **seven years** out of date.

Comment: This is not in my power unfortunately. I am asked to migrate this repository to a git repository, and I am desperately looking for ways to do it. Whatever I tried so far, failed. `svnrdump` seems to be added in the list as well..

Comment: You can't even install a newer client into your user directory? If you don't have the ability to run `svnrdump`, nor do you have access to the server, then what you have been tasked with doing (migrate the repository history) is nearly impossible. Your only option remaining is to check out each revision of the repository and commit them, serially, to a new git repository.

Answer (score 1):

Note, once you have copied over the result of a `svndump`/`svnadmin dump` (as recommended in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148076/6309)), [svn2git](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git) or [subgit](https://subgit.com/) can be used to import it to a Git repository.

Once upon a time (2009-2012), there was a vcs-svn experiment to convert an SVN "dumpfile" to a Git fast-import stream, but... this is definitively dropped with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit fc47391](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc47391e2478b26d33cae033f13405b6ee6af97b), [commit a006f87](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a006f875e2689cb7df543d5950beadb0416d305b), [commit d7a5649](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7a5649c82dfa83ba8d0253e4140f242dca859a7), [commit b5dd96b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5dd96b70aca364f163f0b3743418779cfe062e6), [commit a04f653](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a04f6531099cabbbb94e3d7be0b3db0b718860ee) (13 Aug 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit afd49c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afd49c39dd0089ab887f77be0a8a5a2fc5054cfa), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`svn`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc47391e2478b26d33cae033f13405b6ee6af97b):drop vcs-svn experiment
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The code in `vcs-svn` was started in 2010 as an attempt to build a remote-helper for interacting with svn repositories (as opposed to `git-svn`).
> However, we never got as far as shipping a mature remote helper, and the last substantive commit was [e99d012a6bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e99d012a6bc8b8647a0389d486b5489557364ea6, Git v1.8.1-rc0) in Oct. 2012.
>
> We do have a `git-remote-testsvn`, and it is even installed as part of "`make install`". But given the name, it seems unlikely to be used by anybody (you'd have to explicitly "[`git clone  testsvn::$url`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fc47391e2478b26d33cae033f13405b6ee6af97b/Documentation/git-clone.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup>, and there have been zero mentions of that on the mailing list since 2013, and even that includes the phrase "[you might need to hack a bit to get it working properly](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CALkWK0mPHzKfzFKKpZkfAus3YVC9NFYDbFnt+5JQYVKipk3bQQ@mail.gmail.com/)").
>
> We also ship `contrib/svn-fe`, which builds on the `vcs-svn` work.
> However, it does not seem to build out of the box for me, as the link step misses some required libraries for using `libgit.a`.
> Curiously, the original build breakage bisects for me to [eff80a9fd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eff80a9fd990de3605063050dae32f969ef18ba8) (Allow custom "comment char", 2013-01-16, Git v1.8.2-rc0), which seems unrelated.
> There was an attempt to fix it in [da011cb0e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da011cb0e77a6d2f7c424c5b7dbf482df4723a11) ("`contrib/svn-fe`: fix Makefile", 2014-08-28, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a60f434e20083e94a33614c36626d97be79d5dd0)), but on my system that only switches the error message.
>
> So it seems like the result is not really usable by anybody in practice.
> It would be wonderful if somebody wanted to pick up the topic again, and potentially it's worth carrying around for that reason. But the flip side is that people doing tree-wide operations have to deal with this code.
> And you can see the list with (replace "HEAD" with this commit as appropriate):
>
> ```
> {
>   echo "--"
>   git diff-tree --diff-filter=D -r --name-only HEAD^ HEAD
> } |
> git log --no-merges --oneline e99d012a6bc.. --stdin
> ```
>
> which shows 58 times somebody had to deal with the code, generally due to a compile or test failure, or a tree-wide style fix or API change.
>
> Let's drop it and let anybody who wants to pick it up do so by resurrecting it from the Git history.
>
> As a bonus, this also reduces the size of a stripped installation of Git from 21MB to 19MB.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` only works across a SSH connection, not HTTPS.  It also requires that you have console access to the server (i.e. your repository is hosted on a Linux/Unix server).  So unless you have a SSH key for the server that houses your SVN repository, which puts you at a `$` or `#` prompt, you will not be able to get the repository files using `rsync` (or `scp`).

If it's a Windows server, then you'll need RDP access (or some way to run commands and then put the files somewhere that you can download them).

For making a backup copy of the SVN repository directory, either `svndump` or `svnadmin hotcopy` will work.  Both have to be executed at a command-line on the server.  You would then need to transfer the dump file (svndump) or the repository directory created by `svnadmin hotcopy` to your local machine.

Comment: Both machines use Linux platforms. However my machine is not the server, I just happen to have a remote access. What shall I use to take a copy of the repository, so that I can migrate it to Git?